# R2OpenBUGS rounding DIC to 4 significant digits

Tags: winbugs, openbugs

I am using R2OpenBUGS to look at many different models, and I noticed that every reported DIC has at most 4 significant digits. This seemed suspicious, so I set DEBUG=TRUE and sure enough, DIC = pD + Dbar is being rounded. Why is this? Can I tell BUGS to not round the DIC, or even better, tell it how to round? I want DIC to at least the ones digit.

Here is the bugs call and below is the deviance output:

out <- bugs(data1, inits=initial.values,parameters.to.save = c("err","b1","b0","pred365"), model.file = mymodel, n.chains = 1, n.iter = 25000,DIC=TRUE,debug=TRUE)

```
Dbar    Dhat    DIC     pD
```

ALS 31430.0 29700.0 33150.0 1723.0

total 31430.0 29700.0 33150.0 1723.0

Answer (score 0):

In the bugs command, what happens if you add the argument `digits = 7` ?

Comment: is it question or answer?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am suggesting that if you add the argument to your bugs command, then the number of significant figures will increase. This definitely works for parameter estimates, but I am not 100% sure if this also works for the DIC.